# C# string concatenation best practice

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, stringbuilder, conventions

I was googling for best c# string concatenation, and I found this at microsoft c# code conventions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

> Use the `+` operator to concatenate short strings, as shown in the following code:

```
string displayName = nameList[n].LastName + ", " + nameList[n].FirstName;
```

But I really prefer (`String.Format`) "`$`" for more readability IMHO:

```
string firstName = "MyName";
string lastName = "MyLastName";
string displayName = $"{lastName}, {firstName}";
Console.WriteLine(displayName); // "MyLastName, MyName"
```

Can you tip me which one do you think is better one? or is just about personal preference?

Thanks!

Comment: Both are valid syntax and both are acceptable and it really depends on your personal, team or organization preferences. The question is actually opinion-based. I personally prefer string interpolation (approach 2) for *most* cases, but not always.

Comment: Concatenating a small number of strings is faster than `String.Format`, but premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev thank you, i really don´t see the point of using the traditional + operator hmmm

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert you mean in terms of technical performance or readability?

Comment: I mean as in "consuming less CPU cycles". Do I myself eagerly concatenate strings now that we have interpolation? No, of course not. If I had some tight loop where string formatting was the bottleneck, it'd be another matter.

Comment: When mentioning a source, please include a link to it. I guess that this was contrasting `+` for short strings against the need for StringBuilder. Not `+` against `.Format()`, that really isn't very significant.

Comment: Before asking whether you really need this to be fast, have you run performance tests that pinpoint this as a hot spot in your actual application?

Comment: I was just asking like: which one do you use and why? because I'm newbie in C#, and reading "C# in a Nutshell" book, I found "$"  utility and get it very useful, but maybe in terms of practices it was oriented for very specifically cases

Comment: `String.Format` as well as `$` is very sloooooow! Because parsing the format string in runtime.

Comment: String format is very slow but unless you run lots of iteration i doubt it will be visible. For example we generate millions of words and concatenate them and just from switching from string format to string builder we have went from 5 ish seconds to less than 40 ms. that's on a 4.5 ghz cpu. our reports shows our average user cpu are 2.2ghz. On a 2.8 ghz it was taking more than 10 seconds. Like i said it depend on your usage.

Comment: I think maybe is worth to lose that bit of performance, and gain more readability

Answer (score 2):

If performance is key `String` concatenation is better because it always out performs the other methods of building strings.
But `String` concatenation takes more memory compared to `String.Format`. So best way to concatenate strings is using `String.Format` or `System.Text.StringBuilder` Object

Comment: In what scenarios does string concatenation ever outperform `StringBuilder`?!??

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringBuilder` for the best performance.
`String.Format` is also good but not an exact replacement for "+" operator on string.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// Append to StringBuilder.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    builder.Append(i).Append(" ");
}
Console.WriteLine(builder);
```

Remember to import namespace:

```
using System.Text;
```

Comment: " but not an exact replacement for "+" operator on string", so which usage do you mean `String.Format` has?

Answer (score 2):

This is over a year old, but top of Google results. Originally I was doing this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// Append to StringBuilder.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    builder.Append(i + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine(builder);
```

Then I thought that's probably defeating the point of using `StringBuilder`. I started doing it like

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// Append to StringBuilder.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    builder.Append(i);
    builder.Append(" ");
}
Console.WriteLine(builder);
```

Finally, I realized I can chain methods to have it like @Habeeb. It got me wondering if there's any performance benefits.

```
$e1 = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$e2 = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()

function ef1(){
   Write-Host "Start Date:" (Get-Date)
   for($i=0;$i -lt 100000;$i++){
      $e1.Append("Hello") | Out-Null
      $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString()) | Out-Null
      $e1.Append("World") | Out-Null
      $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString()) | Out-Null
      $e1.Append("More Lines") | Out-Null
      $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString()) | Out-Null
   }
}

function ef2(){
   Write-Host "Start Date:" (Get-Date)
   for($i=0;$i -lt 100000;$i++){
$e1.Append("Hello").AppendLine($i.ToString()).Append("World").AppendLine($i.ToString()).Append("More Lines").AppendLine($i.ToString()) | Out-Null
   }
   Write-Host "End Date:" (Get-Date)
}
```

This was a rough throw together, and I realize it's in PS. But, `ef1` resulted in 17 seconds, and `ef2` resulted in 3 seconds (not considering milliseconds here). Unless I'm mistaken, chaining methods is insanely performance improving. (And yes, this is possibly not unique to `StringBuilder`, but `StringBuilder` led me to ask this question.)

Update:

Thanks to @cogumel0, I realize now how expensive `Out-Null` is. Increasing the iterations another digit shows `ef1` takes about 4 seconds and `ef2` about 1 second. (I also added the missing write end date for `ef1`.)

```
$e1 = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$e2 = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()

function ef1(){
   Write-Host "Start Date:" (Get-Date)
   for($i=0;$i -lt 1000000;$i++){
      [void] $e1.Append("Hello")
      [void] $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString())
      [void] $e1.Append("World")
      [void] $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString())
      [void] $e1.Append("More Lines")
      [void] $e1.AppendLine($i.ToString())
   }
   Write-Host "Start Date:" (Get-Date)
}

function ef2(){
   Write-Host "Start Date:" (Get-Date)
   for($i=0;$i -lt 1000000;$i++){
[void] $e1.Append("Hello").AppendLine($i.ToString()).Append("World").AppendLine($i.ToString()).Append("More Lines").AppendLine($i.ToString())
   }
   Write-Host "End Date:" (Get-Date)
}
```

Comment: There appears to be (in PS at least) some difference between the two functions - but not in that magnitude. The problem is that piping to `Out-Null` is incredibly expensive. `Out-Null` is a class and you're creating 6 instances of that class per iteration. Each instance then has to invoke 3 methods: `BeginProcessing()` `ProcessRecord()` and `EndProcessing()`. The pipeline is also incredibly expensive. My computer takes exactly the same time as yours to run your code, but replace all `<command> | Out-Null` with `[void] <command>` and my computer takes 350ms for ef1 and 130ms for ef2

Comment: Good to know, didn't realize Out-Null was that costly.

Comment: On another note, never use `Get-Date` when dealing with time sensitive matters. Again you're creating two instances of a class in ef1 and two instances of a class in ef2. Instead use something like `[DateTime]::Now`. The `Now` property returns exactly the same as `Get-Date` but is a static property - does not create an instance of `DateTime` class at all for its invocation. Still, that won't give you an accurate idea of how long something takes to run, so instead I'd suggest using `Measure-Command {<command>}` which gives back a `TimeSpan` object - far more accurate.

Comment: Right, I wasn't even referencing the milliseconds. I just added enough iterations until it was enough of a gap to see in seconds. The testing was a bit lazy.